# Pandas KeyError: when merging 2 dataframes

Tags: pandas, merge

I am trying to merge 2 columns from DF2 to DF1 (Note DF2 has multiple columns). I am merging these columns on "Unique ID".

When I do so I get the following error
`KeyError: 'Unique ID'`

I have read online that the KeyError error can be caused by indexing issues, and not using the exact column names. However I have reset the index and I have checked and double checked that the column we're merging on ("Unique ID") is in both DF1 and DF2.

I would rather not share the DFs as they contain sensitive information

This is the code I am using

`df = pd.merge(DF1,DF2[['System','Platform']],on='Unique ID', how='left')`

Comment: you are only using the columns 'Segment' and 'Platform' from the DF2? So it cannot find 'Unique ID' in the second dataframe.

Comment: @Paul I have updated the question. I am merging the system and platform column for DF2 to DF1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

`df = pd.merge(DF1,DF2[['System','Platform', 'Unique ID']],on='Unique ID', how='left')`

Comment: why do you need to specify the first unique ID

Comment: The column you are merging on should be in both dataframes. `DF2[['System','Platform']]` returns a dataframe without 'Unique ID', so it cannot match that column with the Unique ID column in DF1.